# C# HEX Value to IntPtr

Tags: c#, hex, handle, intptr

I have a hex value to a window i found using Spy++.

the value is: 00010010

Thanks to an answer to a question i asked earlier, i have this code:

```
IntPtr hwndf = this.Handle;
IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("WINDOW HERE", null); ;

SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);
this.TopMost = false;
```

Now, as far as i understand it, IntPtr hwndParent will contain the handle to the window WINDOW HERE. How can i rewrite that line to use my hex handle? I tried:

```
IntPtr hwndParent = (IntPtr) 0x00010010
```

But it didnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Value looks suspiciously like a binary number. Can you confirm this is actually a hex value?

Comment: That's a really low number for a pointer that's supposed to represent a handle. I suspect something's not right with the value you're getting.

Comment: Its the handle to the desktop :P

Comment: The way to get the handle to the desktop is with `GetDesktopWindow`, not `FindWindow`.  And I'm almost positive that's not the right handle.  And I should probably add that the desktop window is special and there are all sorts of things you can't do with it (what "didn't work" exactly?)

Comment: well, when i used spy++

i looked at the Progman process. it has a child process DefView and that has a child process SysListView32. Im trying to make the window appear underneath syslistview32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the hex equivalent of 00010010 is 0x12.  So you could theoretically use

```
IntPtr hwndParent = (IntPtr) 0x12
```

The Windows calculator can do that conversion.  That value doesn't sound correct, though.  Can you explain in more detail how you got that value?

**EDIT:** Your comment mentions that you're trying to get a handle to the desktop window.  There's a function for that: [GetDesktopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504%28VS.85%29.aspx), which returns an IntPtr.  If all you're ever interested in is the desktop window, use that.

Here's the P/Invoke for that function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of IntPtr accepts an initialization parameter:

```
IntPtr hwndParent = new IntPtr(0x00010010);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Convert.ToInt32("00010010", 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 var hwnd = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32({HexNumber}, 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966229/c-position-window-on-desktop) question: It seems you don't want to create a widget/window on top of the desktop but on top of another window instead?
If that's the case, why don't you use FindWindow() to - find that window?

Why a constant value?