# How can I make a window appear behind the desktop icons?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, handle

I am making an app that needs a window appear behind the desktop icons. It must be visible.

I am using C#. But If it's needed I can make C/C++ dll's.

I know this question was already asked, but none of the aswers are realy usefull.
the link to the other question: [C# Set Window Behind Desktop Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978077/c-set-window-behind-desktop-icons)

Comment: What specifically doesn't help you about the accepted answer on that question?

Comment: it doesnt have sample code.

I tried the first answer but it doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Set Window Behind Desktop Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978077/c-set-window-behind-desktop-icons)

Comment: The python use of the hook works, it gives the necessary API hooks in the answer. All that's left is to do it.

Comment: @JonHanna do you mind sharing the python version to achieve this?