# SendToBack on startup not working for two or more modeless forms

Tags: c#, winforms, background

I create several modeless forms on application startup and try to send them to the background immediately after showing (the forms represent some kind of "yellow notes" the content of which gets deserialized on startup).

For just one form this works as expected, for two or more forms they stay in the foreground. What is wrong?

My demo code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSendToBack
{
    internal sealed class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MainForm form1 = new MainForm();
            // MainForm form2 = new MainForm(); // comment in to make it fail!

            form1.Show();
            // form2.Show(); // comment in to make it fail!

            Application.Run();
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSendToBack
{
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnShown(e);
            SendToBack();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't mind the OnClosed, it's only for being able to stop the process. Otherwise it is not part of the problem, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an even better solution to the problem! Instead of sending the forms to the background manually (and keeping them there), I have made the desktop the parent of my forms (see also [C# Position Window On Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966229/c-sharp-position-window-on-desktop)):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    void SetParentWindowToDesktop()
    {
        IntPtr hwndThis = this.Handle;
        IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan", null);
        SetParent(hwndThis,hwndParent);
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        SetParentWindowToDesktop();
    }
```

This has two additional benefits:

1. The forms always stay in the background without any further measures
2. They don't appear in the Alt-Tab-Menu (which I expect from "yellow notes" staying on the desktop)

Since all of this is part of a tray application there is still full control over window creation/destruction and application exit.

Two caveats: Don't use ShowInTaskbar=false because this brings the forms back to the Alt-Tab-Menu (WTF...). SendToBack() makes the forms disappear altogether.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have a blank backdrop screen that I want to be visible but always at the back of other windows. When I tried this code, the backdrop screen disappeared completely.